# How to clear Vector in C++?(not std::vector)

Tags: c++, struct

I have a Vector stuct like this:

```
struct Vector {
   float x, y, z;

   Vector( ) {
    x = y = z = 0;
   }
   Vector(float x0, float y0, float z0 = 0) {
    x = x0; y = y0; z = z0;
   }
}
```

I make a new instant of vector-> Vector v [5];
I filled up this array with numbers, but I want to clear this.

I tried this: v = Vector(); but it doesn't work. (I want to call the default constructor of the Vector, which will clear my array?)

Or the only solution is that go through with a for loop and clear one by one?

Comment: What you are doing works for me (after adding a `;` to the end of your `struct`). I did `Vector v[5];`

Comment: if you want to set them to zero, you could use memset(v,0,5*sizeof(Vector)). It's a really efficient way, but is a bit of hack :) memset is declared in the <cstring> header.

Comment: Your try `v = vector();` should not be accepted by the compiler, since `v` is an array of Vector objects. Please post real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write :

```
Vector v [5];
```

The program just allocates 5 contiguous Vector objects in memory. You can switch from one to another using [] operator but 'v' is not an array object.

If you want to reset all data to 0, like in your constructor you have to go through all elements by hand :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  v[i] = Vector();
```

Or better:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  v[i].reset();
```

Where reset() would be a member of Vector which is in charge of setting values to 0, like the constructor (it is more efficient since it does not construct a new object).

You may prefer using std::vector if you have an array of various size. You would also be able to use std::fill() and other algorithms.

```
std::vector<Vector> v;
v.resize(5);
std::fill(std::begin(v), std::end(v), Vector()); // clears v
```

Comment: Is this personal taste, or why do you not call `v.begin()` and `v.end()` instead of std::begin and std::end ?

Comment: Indeed, I could also have called `v.begin()` and `v.end()`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a `for` loop:

```
Vector v[5];
// ...
std::fill(std::begin(v), std::end(v), Vector()); // clears v.
```

Comment: @Twi: Then you're not writing C++. Are you writing C, perhaps?

Comment: @Twi: Be aware that what you're learning is not considered C++ by many C++ professionals, even if your school claims they're teaching C++.

Answer (score 1):

`Vector v[5];` does not declare a new instance of vector, it declares *an array of five* vectors. You can't assign a single vector to an array of vectors.

You can loop through the array and assign a default-constructed object to each element:

```
for (Vector& i : v)
  i = Vector();
```

If you're not using C++11 you can do it the old-fashioned way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  v[i] = Vector();
```

Comment: To do what? It doesn't help clear an array that already exists, and is unnecessary when declaring the array because the type has a default constructor.